# WebGrease + ECMAScript6 + VIsual Studio 2019 => fails to minify the JS code

Tags: ecmascript-6, minify, webgrease

Long time now i was using VS 2017/VS 2019 with WebGrease + ECMAScript5

[image]

Trying to switch to ECMAScript6 and i get minification error when deploying my App to Azure ( building release version )

When running locally ( debug version ) all is fine

WebGrease version:

```
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Is it related to the libraries that i add in the "bundles" in the BundleConfig?

Comment: I had encontered this also, my scripts (ES 6 using "strict") were built and worked like I want them to do, but when trying to bundle and minify, the minification failed due to a lot of errors. It seems that WebGrease does not support EcmaScript 6. :-(